# Can we put a probability measure on every $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory, boolean-algebras

The following question has puzzled me for some time:

> Let $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ be a nonempty,
>   measurable space. Does there
>   necessarily exist a probability
>   measure $\mu:\Sigma\to[0,1]$?

If there exists a nonempty measurable set $A$ such that no nonempty subset of $A$ is measurable (an *atom*), we can simply let $\mu(B)=1$ if $A\subseteq B$ and $\mu(B)=0$ otherwise. So the problem is only interesting if the $\sigma$-algebra has not atoms. This rules out every countably generated $\sigma$-algebra. An example of a $\sigma$-algebra that has no atoms but supports a probability measure is $\{0,1\}^\kappa$ for $\kappa$ uncountable, which we can endow with the coin-flipping probability measure.

Comment: Pick a point $x \in \Omega$ and define $\mu(A) = 1$ when $x \in A$ and $\mu(A) = 0$ when $x \notin A$. Maybe you're missing a nontriviality assumption?

Comment: @Francois, perhaps an appropriate nontriviality assumption might be $Supp(\mu)=\Omega$, in which case I think the answer is NO, given by letting $\Omega$ be uncountable with the discrete topology, and taking the Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: *slaps my head really hard* Thank you.

Comment: @Otis - what do you mean by Supp in the measurable context?

Comment: @RW: $Supp(\mu) = \Omega$ iff every nonempty open set has positive measure.

Comment: But it seems one can achieve that with countably many point masses, assigned on a countable dense set. 

Comment: Of course "open" and "dense" do not exist in the measurable context.

Comment: Okay, with discrete topology, this will in general fail, for example for $\omega_1$. With the cofinite topology, the remark of JDH applies.

Comment: Note that the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets modulo null sets (on $[0,1]$ or $2^\omega$) has no atoms but  *is* countably generated (as a $\sigma$-algebra$), namely by the (equivalence classes of) rational intervals. 

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra on $2^\omega$ has atoms- the singletons. As a matter of fact, every countably generated $\sigma$-algebra is atomic. Just use a countable generator that is closed under complementation. The intersection of all elements of the generator containing a given point is an atom.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I see now that I misinterpreted the term "$\sigma$-algebra" as "(abstract) Boolean algebra where every countable set has a least upper bound", whereas you clearly meant a (concrete) Boolean algebra, i.e. subalgebra (even sub-$\sigma$-algebra) of a power set algebra $P(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 16):

You write "An example of a σ-algebra that has no atoms but supports a probability measure is $\{0,1\}^\kappa$ for $\kappa$ uncountable, which we can endow with the coin-flipping probability measure."

*[Maharam's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharam%27s_theorem)* says that these are essentially the only ones.  That is: Every Boolean algebra which is equipped with a probability measure (and is Dedekind complete, see below) is isomorphic to a product of the measure algebras on various $2^\kappa$ that you mentioned.  (Including finite $\kappa$, to take care of measures with atoms.)

Dedekind complete means that every subset has a least upper bound.   If you take a $\sigma$-algebra which carries a $\sigma$-additive probability measure, and divide by the ideal of null sets, then the resulting algebra is still a measure algebra and it will be Dedekind complete.

An exposition of Maharam's theorem can be found in [Fremlin's book, volume 3](http://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt3.2004/index.htm). (The theorem I quoted can be generalized to algebras with a "semifinite" measure, which is more general than probability measure.)

Comment: I think one should make this more precise: Every atomless measure algebra is isomorphic to a countable convex combination of "coin flipping measures" with infinite "exponent". Dealing with atoms poses additional difficulties, you cannot construct a single unfair coin flip from fair coin flips.

The original paper by Maharam can be found here: http://www.pnas.org/content/28/3/108.full.pdf+html?sid=5854e64c-7fbf-4ec3-8d23-6b3edb93d895

Comment: Naive question: What would be an example of a $\sigma$-algebra that is Dedekind complete but not isomorphic to a product of the measure algebras on various $2^\kappa$, and hence does not have a probability measure on it, to answer the original question?

Comment: The link in the post no longer works - a current website for Fremlin's book is: https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm and https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm (And here is a [Wayback Machine snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20120503060302/https://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt3.2004/index.htm) from 2012.)

Answer (score 7):

The following is a (corollary of a) theorem of Sierpinskii from 1933:

If $\mu:\mathcal{P}(\Omega) \to [0,1]$ is a probability measure and $|\Omega|$ is smaller than the first weakly-inaccessible cardinal, then there must be a countable $A \subseteq \Omega$ such that $\mu(A)=1$.

Comment: Nowadays, "inaccessible" usually means "strongly inaccessible".  But I think that Sierpinski's theorem talks about "weakly inaccessibles", i.e., regular limit cardinals. 

Comment: @Goldstern: You are right, Sierpinski defines inaccessible as a regular $\aleph_\alpha$ for which $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. I edited accordingly.

Comment: I thought Ulam proved this in 1930, in Satz (A) here: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm16/fm16114.pdf 
Actually, I think what Ulam states is that you can't have all points have measure zero if $|\Omega|$ has no weakly inaccessible cardinal less than or equal to it. It takes a small argument with dependent choice to get from this to every measure having countable support. Is it the case that Sierpiński was the one who proved that part?

Comment: @RobertFurber, I can´t read german all that well but I think you are right about Satz(A) implying the proposition I wrote. I was using Sierpinskii´s Proposition U here:  http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm20/fm20121.pdf which he attributes to Ulam for sets of size $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega That's interesting. I guess the implications between these statements were less obvious back in that era.