# Reference Request: Is every interval-valued probability measure consistent?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Short version: Does every interval-valued probability measure contain a conventional probability measure? I have a sense that this is a basic result about an obscure topic but I am having trouble finding a reference.

---

Let $(X,\Omega)$ be a measurable space, so that $X$ is a set and $\Omega\subseteq P(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. An ordinary probability measure $m$ on $(X,\Omega)$ would be a function $m: \Omega \to [0,1]$ such that

- $m(A^c) = 1-m(A)$ for all $A\in\Omega$
- $m(\bigcup_i A_i) = \sum_i m(A_i)$ for all finite or countably infinite families $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of disjoint sets in $\Omega$.

(These imply that $m(\varnothing) = 0$, by letting $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ be the empty family, and therefore that $m(X) = m(\varnothing^c) = 1$.)

Roughly speaking, an *interval-valued probability measure* instead of giving a precise value for the measure of a set, gives a range of values $\mu(A) = [m^-(A), m^+(A)]$. Formally, an interval-valued probability measure is a function $\mu: \Omega\to P([0,1])$ such that

- $\mu(A)$ is a closed interval in [0,1] for each $A\in \Omega$.
- $\mu(A^c) = 1 - \mu(A)$ for all $A\in \Omega$
- $\mu(\bigcup_i A_i) \subseteq \sum_i \mu(A_i)$ for all finite or countably infinite families $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of disjoint sets in $\Omega$.

(Here, we are using a common abuse of notation for adding/subtracting sets, or sets and constants: "$1 - \mu(A)$" means $\{1 - x: x\in \mu(A)\}$, and "$\sum_i \mu(A_i)$" means $\{\sum_i x_i : x_i \in \mu(A_i)\}$.)

The intuition behind these axioms is that perhaps we don't know the true values of a probability measure $m$; we only know for each measurable set $A$ that $m(A)$ is somewhere in $\mu(A) = [m^-(A),m^+(A)]$. That also tells us $m(A^c)$ is somewhere in $[1-m^+(A),1-m^-(A)] = 1 - \mu(A)$. And if we know that another measurable set $B$, disjoint from $A$, has $m(B)\in[m^-(B), m^+(B)]$, then $m(A\cup B)$ definitely can't be lower than $m^-(A)+m^-(B)$ or higher than $m^+(A)+m^+(B)$. In other words, $\mu(A\cup B)\subseteq [m^-(A)+m^-(B), m^+(A)+m^+(B)] = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$, though the containment may be strict if that reflects information we have about $A\cup B$ that we don't have about $A$ or $B$ separately, e.g. if $B = A^c$.

Examples of interval-valued probability measures:

1. Every ordinary probability measure $m$ gives an interval-valued measure with $m^+ = m^- = m$.
2. More generally, if $(m_i)_{i\in I}$ are a family of probability measures on $(X,\Omega)$, then we can define an interval-valued probability measure $\mu$ by $\mu(A) = [\inf\{m_i(A) : i\in I\}, \sup\{m_i(A) : i\in I\}]$.
3. For any measurable space $(X, \Omega)$, there is the maximally vague interval-valued measure $\mu$ that assigns $\mu(\varnothing) = [0,0]$, $\mu(X) = [1,1]$, and $\mu(A) = [0,1]$ for every other measurable set $A\in \Omega$.

My basic question, for which I would love a reference to the literature, is:

> Given an interval-valued probability measure $\mu$, must it contain an ordinary probability measure $m$, in the sense that for all measurable $A$ we have $m(A)\in \mu(A)$? Or is it possible that $\mu$ is "inconsistent," and no choice of values for $m$ from among those allowed by $\mu$ gives a valid probability measure?

(Note that for example 3 above, this question reduces to the MO question [Can we put a Probability Measure on every $\sigma$-Algebra?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85837/can-we-put-a-probability-measure-on-every-sigma-algebra) to which the answer is Yes for trivial reasons.)

A transfinite induction attempt to construct an ordinary probability measure from an interval-valued measure by making arbitrary choices for one measurable set at a time, then propagating the new constraints to create a new interval-valued measure with narrower intervals, seems to work just fine (so far), but the process is tedious and I'd love to reference it if the argument already exists elsewhere.

Comment: Did you invent the notion of an interval-valued probability measure, or is there existing literature?

Comment: @NateEldredge They came up in relation to density of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, but no, I got the definition from [this paper by Jamison and Lodwick](http://ccm.ucdenver.edu/reports/rep213.pdf), which I've rewritten here in an equivalent (but hopefully clearer) form.

Comment: I this fuzzy probability as f.i. in https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5213/18f77cafb280fdb45c859717c1e15100a492.pdf ?

Comment: @DieterKadelka I don't think it's quite the same as the fuzzy probability developed in that reference, which has fuzzy sets as inputs but outputs ordinary numbers. This version of probability has ordinary sets as inputs but outputs intervals; in a sense, the fuzziness is "on the other end."